# How do I go about avoiding buffer overflow when reading numbers from a text file into an array? ISO C17 windows

Tags: c

I am attempting to read numbers from a text file (currently 1m+) and am running into a buffer overflow scenario. I imagine it has something to do with my array's memory allocation but I am absolutely sized up as to how to fix it. I realize my code may be (is probably) sloppy and/or incorrect; any guidance to coding style or readability improvements would be greatly appreciated.

I will be removing the printf statement(s) once I can verify that all numbers from the text file can be successfully read into an appropriately sized array.

My code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


#ifndef NDEBUG
    printf("DBG: argc = %d\n", argc);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("DBG: argv[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);
#endif

    FILE* stream = stdin;   

    if (argc == 2) {
        stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (stream == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error, <%s> ", argv[1]);
            perror(" ");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Enter a list of whitespace-separated real numbers terminated by EOF or \'end\'\n");

    
    char ch = 0;
    int cline = 0;

    size_t arrsize = cline * sizeof(double);

    double* fileArr = (double*)malloc(cline * sizeof(double));
    if (fileArr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    double number = 0.0;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(stream); ++i) {
        while (fscanf(stream, "%lf", &fileArr[i]) == 1)
        {
            
            printf("%.0lf\n", number);
            if (fgetc(stream) == '\n') {
                cline = cline + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(stream);


    /*DELETE AFTER FILEARRAY CAN BE INSTANTIATED WITH THE CONTENTS OF THE FILE*/
    printf("\nSTUB\t\t There are %d lines\n\n", cline);

    size_t size = cline;

    //test print the array to verify it's contents before sorting/ remove after verfied. 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%.0lf\n", fileArr[i]);
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're allocating an array of size `cline = 0` and then reading into it?  That's not going to end well...

Comment: The usual way of doing this is to have two variables, maybe `nread`, the number of entries you've read, and `nalloc`, the number of entries you've allocated.  `nread` starts out as 0.  `nalloc` can start out either as 0, or some initial allocation.  But *before* reading an entry, you test `nread <= nalloc`, and if that's true, it's time to call `realloc`.

Comment: @SteveSummit I am just now seeing this. I feel like a day's worth of coding/studying/parenting has put sand in my brain because I can't put together how to re-organize it

Comment: right! realloc. Of course I missed that

Comment: also you are allocating multiples of `sizeof (double)` which is not the size of numbers in a text file.

Comment: I'd probably just use a [simple geometric growth pattern](https://godbolt.org/z/jfvPGfhMb). ymmv.

Comment: @WhozCraig this is my first experience with Compiler Explorer and I have to say I am impressed, thank you for your comment!

Comment: I don't believe this is correct, either: `for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(stream); ++i)`.  SUGGESTION: just read until you hit end-of-file.

Comment: To elaborate on what @paulsm4 said, `stream` is just a `FILE*`, so `sizeof(stream)` will just be the size of a pointer, either 4 or 8 bytes. `szeof(stream)` does not somehow magically tell you how many bytes are in the file.